# save settings for umatrix and ublock

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, ublock

I enjoy using Umatrix and Ublock, but run into the following problem. I use quite restrictive settings and then manually allow certain elements on certain sites. 
However, I notice that these "settings" sometimes get lost, perhaps when cache or so gets cleaned up (by ccleaner, for example).
Anyway, that is all fine, as long as I am able to reload a settings file with all my settings. I don't know if it is possible to make such a file, so I need to re-do all of my settings frequently. This is annoying and takes unnecessary time. Is it possible to (incrementally) save the various settings I have for the various websites I use? I would like to be able to add new websites to it as I go along. Is that a feature I have been overlooking?

(my main browser is Chrome, so if it works here and nowhere else, it would still be useful progress)

Comment: Clearing cache or cookies certainly doesn't remove configuration settings for the addons. **Are you running uBlock Origin or uBlock**? Origin is the maintained version, I should have asked that right away.

Comment: for uBlock I have the one from https://www.ublock.org, version 0.9.5.0.

Comment: Your fork isn't maintained anymore. uBlock Origin is also by the original developer, please install from your browser addon store.

Answer (score 3):

For UMatrix click the icon then click the titlebar

[image]

Then click the about tab

[image]

Note: you can also use the cloud sync features but for me, I have 8 chrome profiles of which only 3 are connected to accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The uMatrix version (1.3.16) I use in Firefox has an option in its settings like (translated from German):

> ☑ Enable support for saving in the cloud

Comment: Do you know if this option allows the setting to be also applied on all devices once logged in with a firefox account ?

Comment: @m.raynal I don't know. I don't use one. But you could try and add that info to my answer.